# Double negation proof

Tags: agda

Sorry for my English. I used Google Translate.

Is it real to prove for arbitrary type (X : Set)?

```
double-negation : ∀ X → ¬ (¬ X)
double-negation = ?
```

Where:

```
data ⊥ : Set where

data ¬_ (X : Set) : Set where
    ¬-constructor : (X → ⊥) → ¬ X
```

For example, it's simple to prove for ℕ:

```
data ℕ : Set where
    zero : ℕ
    suc  : ℕ → ℕ

double-negation : ℕ → ¬ (¬ ℕ)
double-negation n =
    ¬-constructor negation-contradiction
    where
        negation-contradiction : ¬ ℕ → ⊥
        negation-contradiction (¬-constructor ν) = ν n
```

But after replacing `ℕ` with `X`, it can't be checked (because type of n is unknown, consequently type of `negation-contradiction` is unknown. Also it can't be inferred (I get `¬ n → ⊥`)).

How can I prove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot prove

`∀ X → ¬ (¬ X)`  (1)

Keep in mind that

`ℕ → ¬ (¬ ℕ)`

is not an instance of (1) but

`∀ X → X → ¬ (¬ X)`

which can be proved.

Comment: Thank you. But now I try prove `∀ X → ¬ (¬ X) → X`. It seems that it's impossible, because `X` hasn't known constructors and no argument can return an instance. Is this true?

Comment: It is right we cannot prove `∀ X → ¬ (¬ X) → X`, but your justification is wrong. Can you prove `¬ (¬ ℕ) → ℕ`?

Comment: Yes, I can: `proof : ¬ (¬ ℕ) → ℕ` and `proof _ = zero`. `zero` is constructor, which allows create instance of `ℕ`. But for arbitrary `X` I can't create instance. Where is mistake?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was thinking in the possible proof when you define `¬_ : (X : Set) → Set` by  `¬ X = X → ⊥`, so `¬ ¬ ℕ → ℕ` is `((ℕ → ⊥) → ⊥) → ℕ` (in this case your `proof _ = zero` also works). In the general case, i.e. `∀ X → ¬ ¬ X → X` you cannot build a term of type `X → ⊥`.

Answer (score 4):

`∀ X → ¬ (¬ X)` reads like "all propositions are not false". But `⊥` (and many others) is false, so we can actually disprove your statement:

```
open import Function
open import Relation.Nullary
open import Data.Empty

nope : ¬ ((X : Set) -> ¬ (¬ X))
nope c = c ⊥ id
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me